# Photo preview is shown but photo is not saved in form: using Carrierwave and preview photo with JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, image-uploading

I'm trying to update a profile picture from a user through a (edit)-form. I want to show the user which photo it is trying to upload, so I've used JS to preview the selected photo. The problem is that the preview is showing, but the new photo isn't saved through the form.

Any ideas on what I might have missed?

`edit.html.erb`

```
<%= f.inputs do %>
 <% if @user.photo? %>
  <div id="photo_edit">
    <img id="img_prev" class="profile_photo_edit" src="<%= current_user.photo %>">
     <label id="photo-edit-button">
      <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
      <%= f.file_field :photo %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :photo_cache %>
      <span>Wijzig foto</span>
     </label>
  </div>
 <% else %>
  <div id="photo_edit">
   <%= image_tag "PICA.jpg", :id => "img_prev", :class => "profile_photo_edit"%>
    <label id="photo-edit-button">
     <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
     <%= f.file_field :photo %>
     <%= f.hidden_field :photo_cache %>
     <span>Wijzig foto</span>
    </label>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

`photo-preview.js`

```
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#img_prev')
        .attr('src', e.target.result)
        .width(100)
        .height(100);
      };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
      }
    }
```

`users_controller.rb`

```
    class Profile::UsersController < ApplicationController
      skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
      before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]


      def index

      # pagination
      @users = User.order(:name)

      query = params[:search].presence || "*"
      @results = User.search params[:search], page: params[:page], per_page: 9

      # @results = User.search params[:search], where: {id: {not:         current_user.id}}
    end


    def create
      @user = User.new(user_params)

      if @user.save
        redirect_to :action => 'show'
      else
        render :action => 'edit'
      end
    end

    def new
      @user = current_user
    end

    def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      map
      @competences = @user.competences.all
    end

    def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @profiles = Profile.all
      @locations = Location.all
      @positions = Position.all
      @competences = Competence.all
    end

    def update
      @user = User.find(params[:id])

      if @user.update_attributes(user_params)

        print "--------"
        @bla = []
        @usercompetence = @user.competences

          # Insert / add expertises
          for competence in params[:expertises]
            print competence

            if competence.blank?
              next
            end

            print "\n"
            comp_object = nil

            if Competence.exists?(id: competence)
              comp_object = Competence.find(competence)
            elsif Competence.exists?(name: competence, user_id: current_user.id)
              comp_object = Competence.where(name: competence, user_id: current_user.id).first()
            else
              comp_object = Competence.new(name: competence, user_id: current_user.id, category: "expertise")
              comp_object.save
            end

            print "adding..."
            print comp_object[:name]
            print comp_object[:category]
            print "\n"
            @bla << comp_object

            unless @usercompetence.include?(comp_object)
              @usercompetence << comp_object
            end
          end

          # Insert / add expertises
          for competence in params[:competenties]
            print competence

            if competence.blank?
              next
            end

            print "\n"
            comp_object = nil

            if Competence.exists?(id: competence)
              comp_object = Competence.find(competence)
            elsif Competence.exists?(name: competence, user_id: current_user.id)
              comp_object = Competence.where(name: competence, user_id: current_user.id).first()
            else
              comp_object = Competence.new(name: competence, user_id: current_user.id, category: "competence")
              comp_object.save
            end

            print "adding..."
            print comp_object[:name]
            print comp_object[:category]
            print "\n"
            @bla << comp_object

            unless @usercompetence.include?(comp_object)
              @usercompetence << comp_object
            end
          end

          # Delete competences from user
          print "--------"
          for competence in @usercompetence
            print "Checking.."
            print competence[:name]
            unless @bla.include?(competence)
              print "Delete..."
              @usercompetence.delete(competence)
            end
          end
          print "-------------"

          @user.save

          redirect_to :action => 'show'

        end
      end

      def destroy
        Profile.find(params[:id]).destroy
        redirect_to :action => 'new'
      end

      private

      def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :current_position, :position_description, :email, :phonenumber, :linkedin, :skype, :location_id, :location_specs, :photo, :photo_cache)
      end


      def map
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        if @user.location_id
          @location = Location.find(@user.location_id)
        end
        @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@location) do |location, marker|
          marker.lat location.latitude
          marker.lng location.longitude
        end
      end

      def correct_user
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        redirect_to(root_url) unless @user == current_user
      end

    end
```

user.rb

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
      :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

      mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader

      searchkick
      paginates_per 6

      before_save :generate_competence?

      belongs_to :location
      has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
      has_and_belongs_to_many :competences

      def search_data
        attributes.merge(
          competence_name: competences.map(&:name),
          location_name: location(&:name)
          )
      end
    end
```

Comment: add full controller code and your model too. Also logs can be helpfull

Comment: @sig thanks, will do